# How to integrate custom qml components

Tags: testing, qml

I have my own custom components. How that can be expose to qml unit test framework.

Currently whenever I use rectangle qml type it is working with qml `your text` test. But when I use any custom qml components.

Getting 'customcomponents' not available error.

```js
Item
{ 
    Rectangle {} 
    CustomQml{} 
    
    Testcase
    {
        function test() {
        //rectangle id are working            //here but when use CustomQml id //shows not available issue
    } 

}
```

Comment: This means QQmlEngine cannot find the module, did you set QML2_IMPORT_PATH correctly?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In customQml qml component I have import  MyApp.custom.area 1.3 . and when I run qmltestrunner -input test_mytest.qml. 
I’m getting module  “ MyApp.custom.area” is not install errors  
When I build app , That time I’m not getting this error. So my doubt is how qmltestrunner knows about these components

Answer (score 0):

If you use QT Test and you have a setup.cpp class (gets generated if you use the QtCreator Wizard) you can add the path to your component there...

```
void Setup::qmlEngineAvailable(QQmlEngine *engine)
{
   // custom code needed by QQmlEngine, 
   register QML types, add import paths,...        
   engine->addImportPath("path/to/your/module");

}
```

Comment: How about qmltestrunner, how it can access    tst_myqml.qml internal import dependencies.

Comment: My doubt is about qmltestrunner, not specifically to QTest

Comment: read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicktest-index.html#executing-c-before-qml-tests to find out more how to include the C++ setup code for the testrunner executing your tst_XXX.qml files.